# I am getting FCM firebase token but not getting notification. Also I am not able to check whether the token is valid or not

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

Its working on android but not on IOS

currently I am getting this token

```
:edpGGNf8N0k7mrIwbYWgyX:APA91bF50DO7DOMoIt2sQ2Sp2ptDqIQl1RxKtWbWu-Y3OaSTpsoXObhGyU4wxtpZZxjR7zYHVsEmgwIehMBIFRo4_OmVMhXVovksQVAGRAgT8SShd3Nofm0W72lMhD7orJnHCX61YOeJ
```

General:

- iOS: 10.15.6
- ionic version: 6.11.8
- cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated: ^6.4.3
- @ionic-native/fcm : ^5.36.0

what could be the issue. How to fix this?

Comment: do you define APNS authentication in the Apple developer account and add the key you defined to your firebase console?

Comment: yes I have already done these steps. can you please verify that this fcm token is valid or not ? because I have doubt on it .

Comment: can you please tell us that which cordova fcm plugin version should I have to use for ionic 6.11.8

Comment: how to get or gain the fcm token?

Comment: do you can any firebase set up guide or steps for ionic 6 IOS ?

Comment: No, I can't, I'm not an ionic developer, I'm an iOS, Flutter developer.

Comment: Please don't post exactly same question multiple times. Since this has comments and answer, please delete the other one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71792587/i-am-getting-fcm-firebase-token-but-not-getting-notification-also-i-am-not-able

Answer (score 1):

You must define APNS authentication key in the Apple developer account and download it:

[image]

and go to your firebase console:
Project Settings/Cloud messaging

[image]

then upload the key you defined to this section in bottom of the cloud messaging section in your iOS app:

[image]